# SharePoint Online Webhook - how to get deleted file details

Tags: sharepoint-online, webhooks, getchanges

I am using a webhook to capture events in a document library. And based on the sample from pnp team https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-samples/blob/master/Samples/WebHooks.List/SharePoint.WebHooks.Common/ChangeManager.cs
i am able to get the change related to a deleted file, but the return object only provides the item ID and nothing else related to the deleted item. No File Path, File type, name, title or deleted by. How can I get these details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to get more info on deleted items in web hooks. So, you should use ItemDeleting [remote event receiver](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/voyage/2014/06/11/remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint-2013/) instead.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Will switch to RERs. I hope MS can provide more info in these change objects in the future.